# initializing sidenav width in materializecss 1.0

Tags: materialize

I'm moving from the old version of materializecss to the version 1.0.

I used to set the side nav width by passing the `menuWidth` value during initialization.
for the small screens, I preferred to set `menuWidth: $(window).width()` and I add a close button that call `$('.button-collapse').sideNav('hide');`

after upgrading to the version 1.0 I could not pass that parameter.

is it still possible to define my own width in the new version?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a CSS class on your `<ul>` element that contain the sidenav. This class must have the properties `width` with the `!important`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can only get that with css now:

```
<ul id="slide-out-filter" class="sidenav fixed" style="width:100%">
```